# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/checkemail")

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I add checkemail validation to my Rails 3.2.6 application, which is working fine.
I added the same in Rails 4.2.6 application, it showing errors in the RAILS_ENV=production rails s.
Is there any change in "on change event" or routes declaration with Rails 4.2.6?
Please help
This is the error I am facing:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/checkemail"):
>   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in`call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`public_send'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'   passenger (5.0.30)
>   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in`
>   process_request'   passenger (5.0.30)
>   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'   passenger (5.0.30)
>   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in`main_loop'   passenger (5.0.30)
>   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block
>   (3 levels) in start_threads'   passenger (5.0.30)
>   src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in`block in
>   create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

And these are the files:

**routes.rb:**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" } do
  get '/checkemail' => 'sessions#checkemail', :as => 'checkemail'
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb:**

```
def checkemail
  @checkemail = User.find_by_email(params[:checkemail])
  if @checkemail.present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: "0" }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: "1" }
    end
  end
end
```

**app/sessions/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path, :remote => true, :format => :json, :html => { :id => 'mainLogin' }) do |f| %>
    <input type="hidden" id="email_flag" value="0">
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email address', :input_html => { :placeholder => "Email"} %>
        <label id="error_explanation1" class="error errorExplanation" style="margin-top:-25px; color:red;"></label>
    <%= f.input :password, :label => 'Your password', :input_html => { :placeholder => "Password"} %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.buttons do %>
        <%= f.commit_button :label => 'Sign me in', :button_html => {:class => 'login submit button', :disable_with => 'Wait...', :id => 'user_submit' }%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#user_submit" ).click(function(e) {
  var userEmail = $("#user_email").val();
  var v1 = validateFirstPage();
  if(v1){
   return false;
 }else{
  return true;
}

});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( document ).on( "change", "#user_email", function() {
        var email = $("#user_email").val();
        var url = "/checkemail?checkemail="+email;
        $.get( url, function( data ) {
            $("#email_flag").val($.trim(data));
        });
    });
});
function validateFirstPage(){
    var email_flag = $.trim($("#email_flag").val());
    var userEmail = $.trim($("#user_email").val());
    if(email_flag =="1"){
       var error_msg = "Email doesnot exists";
       $("#error_explanation1").html(error_msg).fadeIn();
    }else{
        if(userEmail != "" && email_flag !="1"){
           $("#error_explanation1").html("").fadeOut();

        } else{
            $("#error_explanation1").html("").fadeOut();
        }
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: please run rake routes | grep checkemail for get route is exist or not

Comment: It is showing nothing. Blank..

Comment: so there is no any routes for the checkemail

Comment: yes. It is routes problem right? Actually I have written the method in sessions controller. How can I write in routes.rb file?